# Sending Excel Chart To PowerPoint Quality And Size

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

This is the code that I have for sending charts to a specific location is the following:

```
Sub This()


Dim PPApp  As PowerPoint.Application
Dim PPPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim PPSlide As PowerPoint.Slide

Set PPApp = New PowerPoint.Application
Set pptPres = PPApp.Presentations.Open("C:\Template.pptx")


Set PPApp = GetObject(, "Powerpoint.Application")
' Reference active presentation
Set PPPres = PPApp.ActivePresentation

' Copy the range as a picture
Sheets("Plots").ChartObjects("Chart Name").Copy
' Paste the range
With PPPres.Slides(10).Shapes.PasteSpecial
        ' Align pasted chart
        .Align msoAlignCenters, True
        .Align msoAlignMiddles, True
End With

End Sub
```

So this does what it is suppose to it opens up a specific PowerPoint slide and sends the chart to slide 10. My question is, is there a way to send the plot to a specific location and make it a certain size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub This()


Dim PPApp  As PowerPoint.Application
Dim PPPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim PPSlide As PowerPoint.Slide

Set PPApp = New PowerPoint.Application
Set pptPres = PPApp.Presentations.Open("C:\Template.pptx")


Set PPApp = GetObject(, "Powerpoint.Application")
' Reference active presentation
Set PPPres = PPApp.ActivePresentation

' Copy the range as a picture
Sheets("Plots").ChartObjects("Chart Name").Copy
' Paste the range
With PPPres.Slides(10).Shapes.PasteSpecial
        ' Align pasted chart
        .Top = 100.84976
        .Left = 85.98417
        .Height = 120.7964
        .Width = 546.5262
End With

End Sub
```

PasteSpecial has the characteristics of having `.Top .Left` and so on. So those can be used to align and resize the photo. I also noticed that if you use `Paste` and not `PasteSpecial` then the photo quality is worse.

Comment: At the risk of being pedantic:  PasteSpecial is a method that returns a ShapeRange object.  It's the ShapeRange object that has .Top, .Left etc. properties.  Yep. OK.  FullPedantry achieved.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg always good to know what the proper lingo is.

Comment: @AdamWarner so you used 90% of my code, and didn't give me the +1 ?

Comment: @ShaiRado your code was giving me an error before so I did not give you a +1. I just did.

Answer (score 1):

Adam, try the following code, works well with the tests I've done on my PC.

The chart location and size were modified according to the values I've entered in the last 4 lines I added.

```
Sub This()

    Dim PPApp  As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim PPPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
    Dim PPSlide As PowerPoint.Slide

    Set PPApp = New PowerPoint.Application
    Set pptPres = PPApp.Presentations.Open("C:\Template.pptx")

    ' Reference active presentation
    Set PPPres = PPApp.ActivePresentation

    ' Copy the range as a picture
    Worksheets("Plots").ChartObjects("Chart Name").Copy

    Set PPSlide = PPApp.ActivePresentation.Slides(10)

    ' Paste the Chart
    With PPSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial
        .Top = 100
        .Left = 120
        .Height = 200
        .Width = 400
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I get an error saying ShapeRange (unknown member): Invalid request. To select a shape its view must be active.

Comment: I got an error on the PPApp.Shapes.PasteSpecial.Select line

Comment: @AdamWarner try the modified code. B.T.W the code before was working for me, I tested it a few times without getting your errors (strange)